# Loading NSImage from icon File takes very long for Visual Studio Code icon

Tags: swift, nsimage

I am trying to load an app icon from an icns file.
I am using the following code:

```
    guard let url = NSWorkspace.shared.urlForApplication(withBundleIdentifier: "com.microsoft.VSCode") else { return nil }
    let icon = NSWorkspace.shared.icon(forFile: url.path)
```

This seems to work very fine for all apps that I tested. All of them? No. Loading the icon for Visual Studio Code takes 4-5 seconds.

Are there any other, faster methods? I also tried to use

```
NSImage(contentsOfFile: url.path)
```

which also takes very long.
I have uploaded the icns file [here](https://sascha-simon.com/Code.icns) (you can of course just use the icns file that comes with your Visual Studio Code installation on macOS, Code.icns).